# Synchronize rotation of Background and Headline

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, rotation

I have one background on a page and one headline. I need them to rotate every time the page is visited. I have found tonnes of image rotation scripts where you just reference the script as if it were an image in the css but I cant find one that I could call back a headline for each image too. Does anyone know of anything that could help me out? (Stopping short of learning PHP inside-out)

For example

```
<html>

 <head>

  <title>Page Title</title>

  <style>

   body {
     background: url('this-image-needs-to-change.jpeg');
   }

  </style>

 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>At The Same Time As This Header</h1>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This wont be anything related to PHP (PHP is backend ie server - this is front end - ie browser) .. this will be pure CSS or CSS and JavaScript ... add your current markup to your question and you might get a better response

Comment: All the rotation scripts I have seen so far have been written in PHP...

Comment: Then maybe i read your question wrong ... I read it as if you wanted an image to rotate ... i think you mean you want to change what image is displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomizing using PHP is easy, just do:

```php
 <?php
     $bgs    = array("bg1.jpg","bg2.jpg","bg3.jpg");
     $titles = array("Title1", "Title2", "Title3");

     $currentIdx = array_rand($bgs);
 ?>

 <style>

 body {
   background: url('<?php echo $bgs[$currentIdx]; ?>');
 }

 </style>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $titles[$currentIdx];?></h1>
 </body>
```

Should do the job.

Comment: This is half of what I am looking for. I really need the content of the <h1> tag to change WITH the image.

Comment: So:
Image 1 has a title that goes with it
Image 2 has a title that goes with it
Image 3 has a title that goes with it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the image to change every time a specific user visits a page, or everytime any user visits a page?

E.g. person 1 views page 3 times and sees images 1, 2 + 3. Person 2 comes along, does he see image 1 or 4?

If the specific user, you will want to store a cookie that keeps track of what image count they are on. Then on index.php: Check if cookie exists, if so, add 1 to it and save it, then get the image corresponding to that number and output it. If not, set the cookie, and get the image. There are a few different ways you could grab some text relating to the image. You could use a database, a notepad file or even hard code the text into the webpage. Gonna have to clarify on that for more specific help I fear

If you want the image to change for every user, you will need to have a database as you will have to store some information on your side. I can't really see why you would want to do this so won't bother explaining it.